# css first child not working when selection is inside another class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got the following html

```
<div class="product-info-top">                    
<div class="price-box">
    <span class="regular-price hide-in-list">
        <span class="price">$10</span>                                    
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="minimal-price-link">
        <span class="price">$8.50</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="product-name-wrap">
    <h2 class="product-name">
        <a href="#" title="Sleepers V2 Insomniac">Sleepers Insomniac</a>
    </h2>
    <p class="parent-cat-name">Playing Cards</p>                    
</div>
```

And I want to select with css only the first `span` with `class="price"` and it works the following way:

```
.product-info-top .price-box .price:first-child
```

And I get the span with the $10 price in this case.
But when the html is like this:

```
<div class="product-info-top">                     
<div class="price-box">                             
    <p class="old-price">
        <span class="price">$7.49</span>
    </p>
    <p class="special-price">
        <span class="price">$5</span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="product-name-wrap">
    <h2 class="product-name">
        <a href="#" title="LTD Purple">LTD Purple</a>
    </h2>
    <p class="parent-cat-name">Playing Cards</p>                    
</div>
```

It does not work because it's the `span` with `class="price"`is inside `p` tag
How can I make css selector which works for both examples ?

**Edit:**

There is one more thing I need to select along with the other ones
**hmtl:**

```
<div class="product-info-top">                                                      
<div class="price-box">
    <span class="price">$29.95</span>                                                                            
</div>  
<div class="product-name-wrap">
    <h2 class="product-name">
        <a href="#" title="All Black Pack">All Black Pack</a>
    </h2>
    <p class="parent-cat-name">Playing Cards</p>                    
</div>
```

I have tried this `.product-info-top .price-box *:first-child .price` but it does not work for the last example

Comment: Your first example doesn't do what you claim it does. You still select both spans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.product-info-top .price-box *:first-child .price {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-info-top">                    
<div class="price-box">
    <span class="regular-price hide-in-list">
        <span class="price">$10</span>                                    
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="minimal-price-link">
        <span class="price">$8.50</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="product-name-wrap">
    <h2 class="product-name">
        <a href="#" title="Sleepers V2 Insomniac">Sleepers Insomniac</a>
    </h2>
    <p class="parent-cat-name">Playing Cards</p>                    
</div>                                      


<div class="product-info-top">                     
<div class="price-box">                             
    <p class="old-price">
        <span class="price">$7.49</span>
    </p>
    <p class="special-price">
        <span class="price">$5</span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="product-name-wrap">
    <h2 class="product-name">
        <a href="#" title="LTD Purple">LTD Purple</a>
    </h2>
    <p class="parent-cat-name">Playing Cards</p>                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can do this with * [the universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) to do the trick.

The `*` `selector` **will see all the child elements** **with class** `price` and will **target** according to the **parent element** ie. `price-box`.

> Below is the working snippet:

```css
.price-box *:first-child .price {
  color: green;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-info-top">
  <div class="price-box">
    <span class="regular-price hide-in-list">
        <span class="price">$10</span>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="minimal-price-link">
      <span class="price">$8.50</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-name-wrap">
    <h2 class="product-name">
      <a href="#" title="Sleepers V2 Insomniac">Sleepers Insomniac</a>
    </h2>
    <p class="parent-cat-name">Playing Cards</p>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

  <div class="product-info-top">
    <div class="price-box">
      <p class="old-price">
        <span class="price">$7.49</span>
      </p>
      <p class="special-price">
        <span class="price">$5</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-name-wrap">
      <h2 class="product-name">
        <a href="#" title="LTD Purple">LTD Purple</a>
      </h2>
      <p class="parent-cat-name">Playing Cards</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.product-info-top .price-box span .price,
.product-info-top .price-box p:first-of-type .price
{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-info-top">
  <div class="price-box">
    <span class="regular-price hide-in-list">
        <span class="price">$10</span>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="minimal-price-link">
      <span class="price">$8.50</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="product-name-wrap">
    <h2 class="product-name">
      <a href="#" title="Sleepers V2 Insomniac">Sleepers Insomniac</a>
    </h2>
    <p class="parent-cat-name">Playing Cards</p>
  </div>

  <div class="product-info-top">
    <div class="price-box">
      <p class="old-price">
        <span class="price">$7.49</span>
      </p>
      <p class="special-price">
        <span class="price">$5</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-name-wrap">
      <h2 class="product-name">
        <a href="#" title="LTD Purple">LTD Purple</a>
      </h2>
      <p class="parent-cat-name">Playing Cards</p>
    </div>
```